# Sprites not showing in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, pygame-surface

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here. There are no errors appearing but when the game loads nothing appears, just the black background. This is the code that I am running for loading my sprite into the game.

```
import pygame
import sys
import os
pygame.init()

"""
Spawn Player
"""

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    pygame.display.set_mode()
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.images = []
        img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("images", "ninja.jpeg")).convert()
        self.images.append(img)
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def Run(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.images = []
        for i in range(1,5):
            run_img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("run","ninja_run" + str(i) + ".jpeg")).convert()
            self.images.append(run_img)
            self.image = self.images[0]
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

"""
Setup
"""
worldx = 900
worldy = 700
fps = 40
ani = 4
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
world = pygame.display.set_mode([worldx, worldy])

player = Player()
player.rect.x = 32
player.rect.y = 32
player_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_list.add(player)

BLUE = (25, 25, 200)
BLACK = (20, 20, 20)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (200, 25, 25)
"""
Main Loop
"""
main = True
while main:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
            break




    #world.blit(backdrop, backdrop_box)
    player_list.draw(world)
    world.fill(BLACK)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(fps)
```

I had a friend look over the code and he said there is a problem with the **init** under the player class but aside from that I really do not understand where the problem within the code is.

The window is calling properly and I'm getting the background as black but the sprite simply will not load.

I'm working with [this](https://opensource.com/article/17/12/game-python-add-a-player) tutorial here to get the sprites to show up. I already have the movement among other parts setup the only thing that doesn't seem to be working is the code revolving around the sprites.

Any help here would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You do `world.fill(BLACK)` immediately for `pygame.display.flip()`.
[`world.fill(BLACK)`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) fills the entire window surface in black and covers everything which was drawn before. [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip) updates the window. This causes that the window is appears completely black.

Change the order of the instructions to solve the issue:

```py
world.fill(BLACK) 
player_list.draw(world)
# world.fill(BLACK)      <---- delete
pygame.display.flip()
```